# Union of two complete graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

> Let $K_n$ be a complete graph of $n$ vertices and there exists two complete sub graphs, namely, $K_i\subseteq K_n$ and $K_j\subseteq K_n$ such that $K_n=K_i\cup K_j$. Then either $K_n=K_i$ or, $K_n=K_j$. Is it always true? Justify.

Here, the graphs are considered to be simple and undirected such that the union of two complete graphs $K_i$ and $K_j$ are defined as: $K_i\cup K_j=\langle V(K_i)\cup V(K_j), E(K_i)\cup E(K_j)\rangle$. As many counter examples as i considered so far seem to satisfy the above statement. Can anyone help me find a counter example in which neither $K_n=K_i$ nor $K_n=K_j$, satisfying the above graphs union?

Comment: Well, the question is: Does this hold? If so (what it does), you are fine to prove it. Hint: If neither is the full graph, what happens to two vertices, each only element to K_i or K_j resp.

Comment: @SonneXo $k_i$ and $k_j$ are both full graphs only. The question is does either $K_n=K_i$ or, $K_n=K_j$ holds whenever $K_n=K_i\cup K_j$?

Comment: I know. What I meant is what happens when neither is the (not a!) full graph aka $K_i \not = K_n$ and $K_j \not = K_n$.

Comment: @SinneXo Ok. You may pose your answer with a brief elaboration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose neither $K_i$ nor $K_j$ are trivial. Then, there has to exist an edge between a node in $K_i$ to one in $K_j$. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible that in the resultant graph $K_n$, there may exist edges between a node in $K_i$ to one in $Kj$ if those edges are common to both, but in that case also $K_n$ fails to be complete unless atleast one of $K_i$ or, $K_j$ is the $K_n$ itself.